# SharePoint Enterprise Wiki Setup

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to setup an Enterprise Wiki for my company, that can be used as a knowledge base. At lot of important information gets lost because of a lack of infrastructure.

The system administrator gave me "contributing" rights on SharePoint.

When I try to create the Enterprise Wiki i get the following error:

```
ERROR

Provisioning did not succeed. Details:Failed to initialize some site properties for Web         at URL:"my sharepoint url/wiki url" OriginalException: <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr>  <nativestack></nativestack>
```

Any help would be appreciated, or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your system administrator create the wiki site for you or are you trying to create that yourself? If you are trying to create the wiki site and not just a new page, you need a higher permission level to do so.

According to the Microsoft support site:

> You must have permission to create a site, library, or pages.
>   Permission levels can be customized, but for most sites, you must have
>   the Full Control permission level to create a site or library, or your
>   administrator must enable self-service site creation. By default,
>   members of the Site Name Owners group have the Full Control permission
>   level, but your site may be set up differently. On most sites, you can
>   create a page if you have the Contribute permission level. By default,
>   members of the Site Name Members group have the Contribute permission
>   level.
>
> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-edit-a-wiki-HA010378214.aspx